# Create Digital Signature in Adobe Reader

Tags: adobe-reader

I'm trying to create a digital signature in a PDF document using Adobe Reader 9 for Mac OSX 10.5.8.  When I click Document -> Sign, all the options are grayed out.  How can I create a digital signature?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have to [create an ID first](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/help.html?content=WS9A8AD2CD-C75D-4a96-A8C8-64125FC6B103.html):

> 1. Choose Document > Security Settings.
> 2. Select Digital IDs, and click Add ID.
> 3. Select Create A Self-Signed Digital ID For Use With Acrobat.
> 4. Follow the on-screen instructions to set up the self-signed digital ID.

Comment: I try this, but the menu is still grayed out.  I notice that when I go to File -> Properties, a field says "Signing: Not allowed."  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Jeffrey Where did you get the PDF?

Comment: A company I am interviewing for wants me to digitally sign a form as part of my application.  I still cannot get Adobe Reader to cooperate, however.  How can I override the protection that Adobe Reader thinks is on the PDF and sign it?

Comment: The best thing I can assume from what you've given me is that they put a password on the PDF so that signing is disabled. Is there a password on the thing (it should say under Document-> Security or whatever)? If so, you may want to remove it with [this program](http://pdfcrack.sourceforge.net/). It's commandline, but it works.

Comment: After building the cracker, it says that my pdf is not password protected, but I still cannot click on "sign" under Documents.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's wrong then. Can you call the person who sent it to you?